# How to increase lvm root parition

Tags: partition, lvm, storage

I am running a centos vm inside freenas. The vm disc is currently 20G and needs to be increased to 60G. I increased it in freenas (edit zvol in the gui). Then I used gparted from a live cd to extend the partition (sda3 in this case). When I get back into centos. I do not see the increase in the cl-root partition. "lsblk" shows the following structure:

```
sda           8:0    0   60G  0 disk
├─sda1        8:1    0  200M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2        8:2    0    1G  0 part /boot
└─sda3        8:3    0 58.8G  0 part
  ├─cl-root 253:0    0 16.8G  0 lvm  /
  └─cl-swap 253:1    0    2G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
```

As you can see, the sda3 partition has much more space than the combined cl-root and cl-swap. How do I use this space towards the cl-root?

Thank you

Comment: Okay, but where is the output of `pvs`, `vgs`, and `lvs`?

Comment: I used lvextend followed by xfs_growfs to increase the logical volume size inside the partition. I still can not wrap my head around this not even on Windows lol

Comment: Thank you for the fast response @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams :)

Comment: You can't increase the LV size inside the partition, only inside the VG.

Comment: The VG was already increased to take the extra space. I wonder if gparted did that

Answer (score 0):

Although `lsblk` presented `/dev/sda3` with a size of 58.8G, that's the size of the partition, not the LVM physical volume. Thus LVM can't see the additional space. Since the partition is the correct size, there are two things that still need to be resized: the physical volume and the root logical volume:

1. `pvresize /dev/sda3`
2. `lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/c1/root`